# ошибка в сафари decodeAudioData

Tags: javascript, safari, web-audio

Есть функиця декодирования аудиофайла

```
await aContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function (buffer) {
        audioBuffer = buffer; 
    }, function (onError) {
        console.log(onError);
    });
    console.log(audioBuffer);
```

Везде работает, а в сафари audioBuffer равен undefined. Что я делаю не так?

Весь код к сожалению не могу скинуть.

```
await aContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function (buffer) {
    audioBuffer = buffer;  // console.log(audioBuffer)  выводит нормально
}, function (onError) {
    console.log(onError);
});
console.log(audioBuffer);  // тут undefined
```

декодирует нормально, только не перезаписывает переменную

Comment: Возможно, сафари не поддерживает формат файла, который вы пытаетесь декодировать.

Comment: Звук записывается с микрофона
http://joxi.net/MAjBJDKC48v4xA  - это сафари 
http://joxi.net/L21GlqyS8W684r - это хром

Comment: Тогда навряд ли, конечно. Необходим полный пример того, что вы делаете. Рабочий, минимальный пример, который бы воспроизводил ошибку.

Comment: Весь код к сожалению не могу скинуть.
await aContext.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function (buffer) {
        audioBuffer = buffer;  // console.log(audioBuffer)  выводит нормально
    }, function (onError) {
        console.log(onError);
    });
    console.log(audioBuffer);  // тут undefined
декодирует нормально, только не перезаписывает переменную

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте данный код в вопрос. В комментарии его очень тяжело читать. Также, приведите полный пример кода! Потому что ошибка может быть в любом месте)